# Excluding specific date and time in cronjob

Tags: cron, date, scheduling

I am trying to schedule a cron job where the requirement is the job has to run every day, every month and every min and every hour EXCEPT 2nd and 4th sunday of every month from 1 to 3 AM.

Is there a way we can do it ?
I have tried using below, but no luck:

```
* 0-1,3-23 1-3,5-17,19-31 * 1-6
```

Comment: Danger danger! You have set both `day-of-month` and `day-of-week` to non-`*` values; these fields unlike the others will cause the command to be run when either field matches the current time. There should be a note in `crontab(5)` about this charming little caveat.

Answer (score 3):

With `cron` alone such specific time exceptions are not possible to configure. Instead you should check that within the script, so that the script will not run when those exceptions are met. This could then for example look like this:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

# If it's sunday ...
if [ "$(date +%u)" = "7" ]; then
  # and it's the 2nd or ...
  if ( [ "$(date +%e)" -gt "7" ] && [ "$(date +%e)" -lt "15" ] ) || \
  # or the 4th sunday of the month ...
  ( [ "$(date +%e)" -gt "21" ] || [ [ "$(date +%e)" -lt "29" ] ); then
    # look if it's between 1 and 3 AM ...
    if [ "$(date +%k)" -ge "1" ] && [ "$(date +%k)" -le "3" ]; then
      # exit the script if all of the above have met
      exit
    fi
  fi
fi

# normal script continues here
```

---

Add this to the beginning of the script.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using dcron, what you could do is set up a job to execute during the entire duration of the period you want to exclude:

```
# crontab
# MIN HOUR DAY MONTH DAYOFWEEK  COMMAND
0 1 1-7,15-21 * 7 ID=naptime /path/to/naptime.sh
```

naptime.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Exit unless Sunday
if [ $(date +%u) -ne 7 ] ; then
    exit
fi
sleep 2h
```

Then you could set up your target job to "depend" on the naptime job:

```
# crontab
* * * * * FREQ=1m AFTER=naptime/1m /path/to/job.sh
```

From [crontab(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/crontab):

> Jobs can be made to "depend" on, or wait until AFTER other jobs have successfully completed. Consider the following crontab:
>
> ```
> * * * * * ID=job4 FREQ=1d first_command
> * * * * * ID=job5 FREQ=1h AFTER=job4/30m second_command
> ```
>
> Here, whenever job5 is up to be run, if job4 is scheduled to run within the next 30 minutes (30m), job5 will first wait for it to successfully complete.
>
> (What if job4 doesn't successfully complete? If job4 returns with exit code EAGAIN, job5 will continue to wait until job4 is retried--even if that won't be within the hour. If job4 returns with any other non-zero exit code, job5 will be removed from the queue without running.)

Answer (score 0):

First, run your script every minute:

```
* * * * * /usr/local/script.sh
```

Then put the logic in it to make it exit immediately if it's:

1. second Sunday or fourth Sunday, or
2. from 1 to 3 AM

This sample script relies on `ncal` and `awk`:

```
#!/bin/bash
second_sunday=$(ncal -h | awk '/Su/ {print $(NF-2)}')
fourth_sunday=$(ncal -h | awk '/Su/ {print $(NF)}')
if [[ $(date +'%d') -eq $second_sunday ]] || [[ $(date +'%d') -eq $fourth_sunday ]]
then exit 0
else
    if [[ $(date +'%H') -ge 01 ]] && [[ $(date +'%H') -lt 04 ]]
        then exit 0
    fi
fi
```

Comment: @amphetamachine Thanks, I don't know what's wrong with the formatting. Couldn't get it to show right.