# Per min cron job that exclude specific time(10pm-12am) everyday

Tags: cron

I have a cronjob that runs every min in 24x7. I want it to stop between 10pm - 12am everyday because that is my maintenance period.
Is there a way i can do that?

Comment: welcome to the linux/unix q+a forum!  Please always do a websearch before asking your questions... the first result on google when I searched for *"exclude time from cron job"* is https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/236120/excluding-specific-date-and-time-in-cronjob which says you have to do the exclusion of 10pm-12am in your script (and not in the contrab).

Comment: @alec The schedule in that question is quite a lot more complex, though.

Comment: The answer is still provided there, though I'm mistaken about the necessity of moving the schedule logic to the script. Thanks @Kusalananda for pointing that out :)

Answer (score 6):

In other words, you want to run it every day at *xx:yy*, where *xx* is any hour from 0 to 21, and *yy* is any minute. That would be starting at 00:00 and ending at 21:59.

So:

```
* 0-21 * * * command...
```

If you wanted to stop at e.g. 21:30 already, you'd need to make a separate rule for that hour:

```
   * 0-20 * * * command...
0-29   21 * * * command...
```

You can easily do it this way since the timeframe here is quite simple. If you wanted to run on a hairier schedule, e.g. every 32 minutes (exactly 45 times a day), the times would spread over the hours almost randomly, and you'd almost need one rule for each hour. It would be simpler to just programmatically look at the time and do the calculation.

Also combining weekdays with calendar dates, like doing the classic "first Sunday of the month", is much harder and usually needs some lines of scripting. (That's basically what the [question linked in the comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/236120/170373) is about.)
In a large part this is due to how the day-of-month and day-of-week fields in `crontab` work: instead of requiring both to match like in the other cases, it's enough for *either* to match, so it's impossible to break the schedule down to smaller `crontab` rules and build from those.